# How do I style the aria label element in HTML

Tags: html, css, label

I'm trying to make a better looking label for a button when you hover over it, i was wondering how can i style the aria-label element to look like this screenshot i added below.

.[image: the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS attribute selector for this.

```
[aria-label] {
position: relative;
}

[aria-label="Search by voice"]:after {
content: attr(aria-label);
/* Your CSS here, this is just a random one for demonstration */
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 110%;
left: 10px;
z-index: 5000;
pointer-events: none;
padding: 8px 10px;
line-height: 15px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0;
overflow: visible;
font-size: .9em;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 0 1px #888;
background-color: #412917;
border-left: 6px solid #d37092;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

a:focus {
  outline:1px dashed #E92C6C;
}

[aria-label]:hover:after, [aria-label]:focus:after {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: When i put this into the CSS and added `aria-label="Search by voice"`, if did not seem to work.

Comment: Check the new edit. I forgot to add display: block, on hover. My bad. Should work fine, now.

Comment: Just as an aside, I'd recommend _not_ styling elements based on aria label values, for the sole reason that aria labels should be translated into the target language of the page, this means that if you introduce internationalization, you will break these styles.

As an alternative you could add a class to the element, and style based upon that